# SQL запрос с получением даты между N

Tags: sql

Пытаюсь вывести из базы данных, данные, в таком порядке: 
Все данные которые ниже или равны данной недели и следующие 4.

То есть, те которые равны этой недели или ниже, как `<=CurrentWeek`, остальные, оставить как есть под номерами.

У нас должно получится следующие, если в базе есть цифры равные нынешней недели или меньше в `[KW]`, выводим как пример `(KW, Gruppe, Summe)` <=45 | 2 | 10000, при этом считая все суммы вместе, что равные нынешней недели или меньше. Все что выше, к примеру: 46 | 1 | 15000, но также считаем суммы вместе.

Примерно как на этом скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытался сделать так.. но выводит, что все `<=45`

```
Select '<=' + Convert(varchar, DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, GetDate())) as KW,
        Gruppe,
        SUM(N_KH) AS Summe,
        Auftrag
FROM [ATX_PLSNG].[dbo].[Terminliste]
Group by Gruppe, Auftrag
```

знаю, что нужно работать с `DATEPART`, но не совсем понимаю, как мне правильно написать данный запрос

Попытка с `DATEPART`

```
Select '<=' + Convert(varchar, DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, GetDate())) as KW,
        Gruppe,
        SUM(N_KH) AS Summe,
        Auftrag
FROM [ATX_PLSNG].[dbo].[Terminliste]
Where DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, KW) > DATEPART(ISO_Week, GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, KW) <= DATEPART(ISO_Week, GETDATE()) +4
Group by Gruppe, Auftrag
```

Comment: Имя поля выходного набора нельзя использовать в секции WHERE.

Comment: @Akina то есть? заменил имена получилось такое https://ibb.co/gJ2w4My

Comment: А причем тут mysql ? в нем нет указанных функций работы с датами, да и  квадратные скобки намекают, что это sql-server например

Comment: @Mike значит выбрал не тот тег. Поменяю сейчас

Comment: Судя по скрину из коментов, у вас в `KW` и так номера недель. Возможно вам не нужно во WHERE делать преобразование `DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, KW)`?

Comment: @RAMe0 обновил немного вопрос, не пойму как все недели, равные этой и ниже, поместить в <=CurrentWeek, а остальные оставить под номерами.

Comment: Вообще он должен быть sql-server (если это он). Но суть остального вопроса совершенно не ясна. Судя по приведенной в комментариях картинке у вас в таблице есть поле KW, но структура таблицы в вопросе не описана и не ясно, что вообще содержится в данном поле. Фраза "_То есть, те которые равны этой недели или ниже, как <=CurrentWeek, остальные, как положенно_" мне не говорит вообще ни о чем, так как не ясно что такое "как положено". И причем тут некий group by, ведь он вероятно так же должен как то поле с датой учитывать, или не должен ? В общем приводите исходные данные и что должно получиться

Comment: @Mike обновил вопрос. надеюсь более понятно..

Comment: Что то вроде `case when KW <= DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, GetDate()) then '<=' + cast(DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, GetDate()) as varchar) else KW end` и его же повторить в group by

Comment: @Mike спасибо, то что нужно было

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select case when KW <= DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, GetDate())
            then '<=' + cast(DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, GetDate()) as varchar)
            else KW end as KW,
       Gruppe,
       SUM(N_KH) AS Summe,
       Auftrag
  FROM [ATX_PLSNG].[dbo].[Terminliste]
 group by Gruppe, Auftrag,
       case when KW <= DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, GetDate())
            then '<=' + cast(DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, GetDate()) as varchar)
            else KW end
```